# Vue.js Scoped CSS - how to match root element?

Tags: css, vue.js

I have the following components:

Component 1:

```
<style scoped>
.root {
    ....
}
</style>

<template>
    <div class="root">
        ...
        <component2></component2>
        ...
    </div>
</template>
```

Component 2:

```
<style scoped>
.root {
    ....
}
</style>

<template>
    <div class="root">
        ...
    </div>
</template>
```

Because the root element of Component 2 also has class `root`, the style of Component 1's root element is also applied to Component 2. How can I prevent this? Is there a way to match on only the root element of a component (and not its children), without crude workarounds like ensuring that all root class names are unique?

---

Edit:

Relevant GitHub issue: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/957

Seems like there is currently no simple fix to this and the non-trivial workaround is to use CSS modules instead of scoped CSS.

Answer (score -2):

if you want to use variables for your components, put all the variables on the app.vue (parent) and then use into your components (children)